# Disable single checkbox using react-checkbox-group in react

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am using this to create a checkbox group:
https://github.com/ziad-saab/react-checkbox-group

I need to disable the first checkbox generated. 
Does anyone know the props to do it?

I have tried:

```html
<label><Checkbox value={i} disabled /> {passo.title}</label>
<label><Checkbox value={i} disabled={true} /> {passo.title}</label>
<label><Checkbox value={i} disabled=true /> {passo.title}</label>
```

Comment: just `disabled` seems to work - https://codesandbox.io/s/14o8x78vkl  , check this out kindly !

Comment: this is a more detailed error

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/qky5vm86qw <- please check

Comment: what is `this.primeiro` in your code? the code doenst enter that conditional block , also i'd say avoid doing this.setState({}) inside your render method

Comment: primeiro = first in portuguese.
I want the first one to be selected by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am guessing you want to **check** and **disable** the checkbox at the same time. It can be done by passing the values to be checked as an array to the `value` property of `CheckboxGroup` component as follows

`<CheckboxGroup name="passos" value={[0,1]} onChange={this.passosChanged}>`

I've used a value of `{[0,1]}` for example . And as statated before you can pass `disabled` to your `<Checkbox>` component.  Attaching CodeSample link below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kwy7x46mjr

In case i have missed something , kindly clarify more !